# Powershell find and replace in Excel

Tags: excel, powershell

I have about 20 Excel reports.. All headers are the same and the formats of the cells are all the same. In column H on a Tab named Response the header is "Sensor Version" the cells are filled with numbers as such 006.002.001454 I am trying to get powershell to find and replace 00 so that there are no preceding 0's in the numbers. Is there a way to do this, and more importantly is there a way to only apply this to column H since other area's of the workbook potentially can have 00 in a cell.

Comment: If you have code you've been trying then it's best to include it in your post, otherwise it's likely to get closed.  See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$excelFile = "excel File.xlsx"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WorkBook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($excelFile)
$worksheet = $WorkBook.sheets.item("Response")
$rowCount = $worksheet.usedrange.rows.count
$ColumnNumber = $worksheet.cells.find("Sensor Version").column

$newValues = $worksheet.usedrange.columns.item($ColumnNumber).value2 |% { $_ -split "00(.)" -join ""}

for ($i = 2; $i -le $rowCount; $i++) {
    $workSheet.cells($i,$ColumnNumber).value = $worksheet.cells($i,$ColumnNumber).text -split "00(.)" -join ""
}

$workBook.close()
```

This will open each file in Read-Only mode, so you will have a prompt for each save attempt. You can loop through each Excel file by encompassing the entire code block in a `ForEach` loop and set each file path value to `$excelFile`.